# Connect to Redis in Hyper-V guest machine from host

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hyper-v, redis

I want to access Redis, and probably other services in the future which are located on my Hyper-V virtual machine (Ubuntu) from my Windows desktop (the host). Only the guest and host should be able to access Redis.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/06/hyper-v-getting-host-guest-connected/) and added a manual IP & subnet mask for

- both the [host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU10H.png)

[image: 2]

and the [guest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYNtm.png).

[image: 3]

The problem is that I can't connect to Redis from the host (my pc). I tried running `ping 192.168.10.100` and it *worked* but `telnet 192.168.10.100 6379` *didn't work*, so it's not an issue with the IP but something else. I assume the issue relates to my [Redis binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apkMr.png) or firewall.

[image: 4]

To confirm: 6379 is the port I use for Redis.

Comment: Look up using Host Only for the Hyper-V Guest as that should do what you want.

Comment: @John First result says to use network switches which I've done already. The thing is that it still doesn't work. (I tried Internal switch, without providing a manual IP to host/guest)

Comment: Try commenting the existing bind and uncomment the one that binds to `0.0.0.0`. Don’t forget to restart redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `sudo ufw allow 6379` and it solved the problem. Also, make sure the Redis bind allows you to connect (adding `192.168.10.100` to the Redis bind should be fine).